# How does JPA determine "dirty" attributes of an Entity object?

Tags: java, jpa, entity

Suppose we have a Program entity with an attribute of "name" which is set as `fetchType = LAZY`.

If I fetch a program and change the name of it to a new name and after transaction ends:

Will it change the value of the name into the new value in database as it was identified to be dirty or no change will happen since "name" was set to `LAZY` ?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Why would a read operation cause an update?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're conflating two different operations here.  Lazy is used to determine when data is read from the database.  If an entity is flagged as lazy loaded, then it won't load any related data, like sub-objects, until it's referenced.  If it's flagged as Immediate, then all data is read whether it will be used or not.

As for reading dirty data, that's dependent on the `isolation` level set within `Transactional` annoation.  Some databases support dirty reads, some do not.  You'll need to refer to the documentation of your database.  If an entity is read using dirty data (again, if allowed by your database) from a yet-to-be-committed transaction, then it will have that data when it commits its changes.

I would caution against using dirty data as there could conceivably be 100s of uncommitted records and you can create a terrible mess to unravel.  I would suggest using a Cache in your main service so entities are managed for you rather than you trying to create your own solution.

Spring and Hibernate are there to manage your data for you.  Let them do their job.  Don't fall into the trap of overthinking your solution.